# Entity Framework is trying to save the Foreign key tables along with the entity save. How to prevent that?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

When i am saving belwo CounterpartyFrequency entity as below, its trying to add the legalEntity attached to it. How can i prevent that. i just need the counterpartyfrequency table to insert with     CounterpartyFrequencyId  and LegalEntityId . Plz share your thoughts

```
[DataContract]
    public class CounterpartyFrequency : EntityBase
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int CounterpartyFrequencyId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LegalEntityId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [ForeignKey("LegalEntityId")]
        public LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
   }
```

The Entity i want to save is above

```
using (var dbContext = ConfigurationContext.CreateContext(dbConnection))
                    {
                        foreach (var counterpartyFrequency in counterpartyFrequencies)
                        {


                            if (
                                dbContext.CounterpartyFrequencies.Any(
                                    (x) => x.CounterpartyFrequencyId == counterpartyFrequency.CounterpartyFrequencyId))
                            {
                                dbContext.CounterpartyFrequencies.Attach(counterpartyFrequency);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               dbContext.CounterpartyFrequencies.Add(counterpartyFrequency);
                            }
                        }

                       var noc =  dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the LegalEntity as virtual:

```
[DataContract]
public class CounterpartyFrequency : EntityBase
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int CounterpartyFrequencyId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LegalEntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LegalEntityId")]
    public virtual LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But still gives the error "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsAffiliate', table 'common.LegalEntity '; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: Thanks , i made the legalentity virtual and when passing null , issue resolved